# Not able to connect mysql database with django framework

Tags: python, mysql, django, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

i am trying to connect mysql database with django framework but it is not getting connect.

Setup: xampp installed,django installed,mysqlclient installed

Created a database using phpmyadmin with the database name as polls

settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'polls',
    'USER': 'root',
    'PASSWORD': '',
    'HOST':'localhost',
    'PORT':'3306'
    }
}
```

error when i run python manage.py migrate:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/akshay/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 216, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/home/akshay/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 194, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/home/akshay/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 234, in get_new_connection
    return Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/home/akshay/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 85, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/akshay/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 204, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/akshay/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/akshay/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 365, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/akshay/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/akshay/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 332, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/home/akshay/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/home/akshay/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 57, in _run_checks
    issues = run_checks(tags=[Tags.database])
  File "/home/akshay/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 73, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/home/akshay/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/database.py", line 10, in check_database_backends
    issues.extend(conn.validation.check(**kwargs))
  File "/home/akshay/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/validation.py", line 9, in check
    issues.extend(self._check_sql_mode(**kwargs))
  File "/home/akshay/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/validation.py", line 13, in _check_sql_mode
    with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
  File "/home/akshay/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 255, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/home/akshay/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 232, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/home/akshay/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 216, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/home/akshay/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/akshay/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 216, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/home/akshay/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 194, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/home/akshay/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 234, in get_new_connection
    return Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/home/akshay/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 85, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/akshay/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 204, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")
```

Comment: check this link https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-mysql-or-mariadb-with-your-django-application-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: did you try to connect to the sql through terminal?

Comment: @HemanthSP i have tried all the step mention in that link, but still it is not working

Comment: @doubleo46 mysql -u root : giving following error 
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2 "No such file or directory")

Comment: sudo service mysql status, 
What is the output of this?

Comment: @doubleo46  
   mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.1.30 database server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: 
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:mysqld(8)
           https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/

Comment: @Akshay Rathod do sudo service mysql restart and try connecting

Comment: sound like `user` issue, if your service (mysqld) run normally, need check all users(on mysql).

Comment: sudo service mysql restart command gave this error -> Job for mariadb.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl  status mariadb.service" and "journalctl  -xe" for details.

Comment: refer this one https://serverfault.com/questions/812719/mysql-mariadb-not-starting

Comment: @dsgdfg what should i do?

Comment: @doubleo46 still same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall XAMPP.
installed the LAMP stack.

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
sudo apt-get install php"version"
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

and it started working.